# AJAX: Access to restricted URI using a Relative Path

Tags: html, ajax

Ok what the heck is wrong with this?

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "../Module1/page1.html", true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Throws
NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied
When I try to load the page, everything is running locally, using Firefox 24.

I can't use any backend server languages when this gets used online, either, so no PHP or ASP solutions will work.  Hooray LMS SCORM content. :U

Now I can do this just fine:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "page1.html", true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Its just that it won't let me load a page in another directory.

Comment: If there's no backend technology, what is the ajax for?

Comment: Do you have permissions to access the directory `../Module1/page1.html`?  And by you, I mean Apache.  You may need to chmod to 755 to the directory and file.

Comment: Are you on a filesystem path with this?

Comment: The ajax is to load static content pages that exist in another directory instead of using iframes.  I suppose I *could* but iframes are ugly.  As to Sable's question: there isn't Apache running, it's all localhost! :o

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently due to cross domain access restriction. When you use relative paths like `/myApplication.html`
the request is send to the same domain where your parent application is placed/hosted. To solve this issue you can use reverse proxy method if you are using Apache.

http://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDOC11/configure-apache-httpd-as-a-reverse-proxy-modproxy.html

or

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html